# Why is php entering data before i press submit

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I dont have previous experience with PHP or SQL so i didnt quite catch everything and i have done this by previous various templates/examples, i manage to connect my form to database but it creates record on load before i enter data and press submit and i cant figure out why, also when i fill form and press submit, it takes me to home page should it do that way (and does not fill in data in table), here is code and thank you in advance!!!

```
    <html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "10.253.---.--";
$username = "intranet";
$password = "----";
$dbname = "intranet";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO AdresarGIS (Adresa, Broj, Mesto, Agent, Komentar)
VALUES ('$_POST[Adresa]','$_POST[Broj]','$_POST[Mesto]','$_POST[Agent]','$_POST[Komentar]' )";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <p>
        <label for="Adresa">Adresa</label><br/>    
        <input type="text" name="Adresa" />
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="Broj">Broj</label><br/>    
        <input type="text" name="Broj" />
        </p>
         <p>
        <label for="Mesto">Mesto</label><br/>    
        <input type="text" name="Mesto" />
        </p>
         <p>
        <label for="Agent">Agent</label><br/>    
        <input type="text" name="Agent" />
        </p>
         <p>
        <label for="Komentar">Komentar</label><br/>    
        <input type="text" name="Komentar" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pošalji" />
        </p>
    </form>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you don't check to see if the form is submitted so the the code is executed when the page loads

Comment: ouch, did you feel that sql injection yet?

Comment: how may i do that ? 
I asume something like this :
if ($_POST["submit"] === "submit" { 
$sql = "INSERT INTO AdresarGIS (Adresa, Broj, Mesto, Agent, Komentar)
VALUES ('$_POST[Adresa]','$_POST[Broj]','$_POST[Mesto]','$_POST[Agent]','$_POST[Komentar]' )";
}

Comment: hint: `if not empty...` http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php and isset http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: *" I asume something like this..."* - you got it Pontiac ;-) in addition to what I wrote above.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is on private intranet site so i avoided injection prevention, since im not skilled enough

Comment: you are putting way too much trust in people. Remember this: *"Even your best friend will (ahem) you"*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for the help very much! i will read it in detail and try to solve it, will also work on injection prevention :D

Comment: you're welcome. *Stay safe, even in the workplace* ;-) most accidents happen there.

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't check to see if the form is submitted so the the code is executed when the page loads. There are a few ways to do this but simply checking if the page was requested via the POST method is the simplest:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    /// your code goes here
}
```

FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: let's not forget `empty()` ;-) on the "if not".

Comment: Yeah, they need to add validation as well but that's beyond the scope of the initial question. :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Comments You have not checked either your `form` is posted or not that's why you are getting blank `values` in your database do this. Use `isset` for this

1) use `isset($_POST['submit'])` to check form data is posted or not

2) Also check posted vales is not `empty` if `empty` then show errors

like

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['Adresa']) || empty($_POST['Broj'])|| empty($_POST['Mesto'])|| empty($_POST['Agent'])|| empty($_POST['Komentar'])){
        echo "Please fill all fields";

    }else {
$sql = "INSERT INTO AdresarGIS (Adresa, Broj, Mesto, Agent, Komentar)
VALUES ('$_POST[Adresa]','$_POST[Broj]','$_POST[Mesto]','$_POST[Agent]','$_POST[Komentar]' )";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['your btn name']))
{
    //your insert query
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if the form is submitted or not

```
<?php
$servername = "10.253.---.--";
$username = "intranet";
$password = "----";
$dbname = "intranet";
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']){    // check if the form is submitted
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
       die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO AdresarGIS (Adresa, Broj, Mesto, Agent, Komentar)
VALUES ('$_POST[Adresa]','$_POST[Broj]','$_POST[Mesto]','$_POST[Agent]','$_POST[Komentar]' )";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
     } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
     }

     mysqli_close($conn);
} // end if
?>
```